# image jumping downwards on a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I'm having problems with a slideshow (the problem is almost the same as this one [Simple jQuery Slideshow Image Moving Downwards for a Split Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968715/simple-jquery-slideshow-image-moving-downwards-for-a-split-second) but its not working for me). The problem is with the `next()` call. I tried to make a kind of sleep function but im not able to call it there.

Here is my code:

**CSS:**

```
.slidePromo { 
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative; 
    width: 700px; 
    height: 300px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slidePromo" class="slidePromo">
    <div><img src="./promos/banner.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="./promos/next.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="./promos/splash.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function slider(id, fade, timer) {
    $("#" + id + " > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() { 
    $('#' + id + ' > div:first')
        .fadeOut(fade)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(fade)
        .end()
        .appendTo("#" + id);
    },  timer);
}
```

any idea? thanks and regards.

Comment: What is triggering this function?

Comment: @Evan $(function() {slider("slidePromo", 1000, 3000); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(100,function(){
    $(this).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
});
},  3000);
```

use a call back function on the fadeout and it will wait until it's completely gone before it appends the other one.

Comment: thats the correct answer. I will accept it as stackoverflow let me do it. Really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be becouse in css you have class `slideShow`, but you wrapper has class `slidePromo`. This css block don't even apply on smth. Change class - it will work without jquery changes.

P.S. jquery code is awful. Try this:

```
function slider(id, fade, timer) {
    var holder = $('#' + id);
    holder.find(" > div:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(function() { 
    holder.find(' > div:first')
        .fadeOut(fade)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(fade)
        .end()
        .appendTo(holder);
    },  timer);
}
```

This is little upgrade.

Comment: Ok, but i test it. http://jsfiddle.net/9n9GK/5/ - here. Just some improve in css - and that's all. And images fade through each other.

Comment: well...in that way i still have the same problem. In your "better" jquery code you just assign the control to a var...thats not a great improve in anyway!

Comment: I agree. This all jquery-code is awful. Author was to lasy to check end of set and return to first element - he decide to move elements in DOM. Great decision, ok.